# Generic extension method on Queryable, Crashes on Invoke when converting expressions to something usable by Linq-to-entities

Tags: entity-framework, generics, expression

I wrote a generic extension method that takes the pain out of parsing a querystring or route data parameter and filtering a certain  queryable based on that parameter.

```
  public static IQueryable VaryBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> input,Func<T,int> navigationalproperty,string routeparameter,PageController currentPagecontroller) where T : EntityObject
    {
        string navid = currentPagecontroller.GetFromRequestOrRouteData(routeparameter);
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(navid))
        {
            int navidasint = int.Parse(navid);
            //return input.Where(x => navigationalproperty(x) == navidasint);

            return (from var in input
                    let result = navigationalproperty(var)
                    where result == navidasint
                    select var);
        }
        else
        {
            return input;
        }
    }
```

this , when working, would allow me to write the following clean line of code in my  controllers, instead of having to copy paste the non-generic version of the above block every time.

```
 return aDB.GetAll<Product>().VaryBy(x=> x.Category.Id, "categoryid", this);
```

Sadly this throws an exception when calling ToList() on the result: **"The LINQ expression node type ‘Invoke’ is not supported in LINQ to Entities."**

I kind of understand why this is happening. I also read that I could maybe use [LinqKit](http://blog.felipel.com/2009/08/the-linq-expression-node-type-invoke-is-not-supported-in-linq-to-entities/)'s AsExpandable for this, but I'm kind of hesitant to use their "automatic solution" before I understand how I could make this work myself,
I'm open to solutions that use a different approach aswell, just trying to learn here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [John Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251153/c-sharp-expressions-easy-conversion-with-or-equals-operator-and-external-para) on my question wich simplified this one, I succeeded at  creating my VaryBy function like this:

```
public static IQueryable VaryBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> input,Expression<Func<T,int>> navigationalproperty,string routeparameter,PageController currentPagecontroller) where T : EntityObject
    {
        string navid = currentPagecontroller.GetFromRequestOrRouteData(routeparameter);
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(navid))
        {
            int navidasint = int.Parse(navid);
            Expression equals = Expression.Equal(navigationalproperty.Body, Expression.Constant(navidasint));
            return input.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(equals, navigationalproperty.Parameters));

        }
        else
        {
            return input;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, think about how you would convert this request into TSQL. If you can't translate it into native TSQL, most likely any framework won't be able to do it either. The If clause and external method invocation are both blockers to translating this into a single query.

Comment: I know this rule of thumb :) Also, the if clause isn't a problem, it's not getting translated anyway since i'm just returning a different IQueryable. The only issue here is the Func that get's invoked, instead of converted into one compilable expression including the "== navidasint" part.. (I think)

Comment: Actually, it might be the NavigationalProperty which you're declaring as a Func<T, int> rather than Expression<Func<T, int>> as a result, the Func can't be evaluated and parsed only executed. Try temporarily removing the Let and Where clauses and see if it compiles and runs to isolate this.