# C# Expressions easy conversion with == or Equals operator and external parameter

Tags: c#, entity-framework, expression

Let's say i had two parameters:

parameter 1 an expression that takes a T and fetches the associated product's ID from it

```
Expression<Func<T,int>> prodIdProperty = x=>x.Product.Id
```

parameter 2 a productid to compare with , let's say

```
int productid = 5;
```

Is there any way I could runtime transform  this (in code) into a new expression like this:

```
Expression<Func<T,bool>> prodIdProperty = x=>x.Product.Id == 5
```

I basically need something like this:

```
Expression<Func<T,bool>> TransformToPredicate(Expression<Func<T,int>> prodIdProperty,int productid){
//insert expression transform magic I don't seem to grasp...
}
```

I need this because I want to pass it as a predicate to my EF Where clause, that means I cannot included Compiled versions of my prodIdProperty as It requires calling Invoke() wich is not supported

(I already tried formulating my problem another way in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212721/generic-extension-method-on-queryable-crashes-on-invoke-when-converting-express) question, but I think I overcomplicated it there)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like:

```
Expression<Func<T, bool>> TransformToPredicate(
    Expression<Func<T, int>> prodIdProperty,
    int productId)
{
    Expression equals = Expression.Equal(prodIdProperty.Body,
                                         Expression.Constant(productId));
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(equals, prodIdProperty.Parameters);
}
```

Sample code showing it in action:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

class Test
{    
    static Expression<Func<T, bool>> TransformToPredicate<T>(
        Expression<Func<T, int>> prodIdProperty,
        int productId)
    {
        Expression equals = Expression.Equal(prodIdProperty.Body,
                                             Expression.Constant(productId));
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(equals, prodIdProperty.Parameters);
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Expression<Func<string, int>> length = x => x.Length;

        var predicate = TransformToPredicate(length, 5);
        var compiled = predicate.Compile();

        Console.WriteLine(compiled("Hello")); // True
        Console.WriteLine(compiled("Foo")); // False
    }
}
```

Comment: Looked great at first, but this doesn't work for me yet, .. Expression.Equals returns a boolean not an Expression, the Expression.Equal (without s) I think you meant,get's me to compile, but throws a runtime expression because it can't compare Binary Expression to an int

Comment: Is there an Equals overload or extension method im missing that isnt in the basic Expressions namespace?

Comment: @Mvision: Sorry, I meant `Expression.Equal`, yes. As for the comparison failing, it should be okay... you're comparing "an expression representing property access" with "an expression representing a constant". Will see if I can test it, then fix it if necessary...

Comment: @Mvision: Doh, got it. You need to take the *body* of the input expression. Editing...

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works Perfectly i'll update my other post aswell!